# RelativeLayout required to display fragment on top of each activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I want to make it possible to display a fragment on top of every activity (if the right action is called). It should look like a window on top of everything. This works fine so far, but I am a bit confused about how to get the layout integration working.

When I wanted to display something like a fragment on top of everything, I had to use a `RelativeLayout` as the root element, then nesting maybe `LinearLayout` (containing the activity's layout) and `fragment`.

Is that the only way to achieve this? Do I have to refactor now every activity layout to use `RelativeLayout` as the base? Or is there a more straightforward way?

Comment: Sorry, why the downvote? Is it an obvious one?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment, so will write here. Please provide some code to express what you mean, much easier to understand it than. If i understood you correct, u want to have a window on top of another window? 
Cannot see why this would be voted down, and not even a comment for the reason :/.

You might achieve what you want with an overlapping fragment. I have had this side effect when making my app, i.e. that a fragment view is transparent on top of another fragment. To achieve this, just skip if(savedInstanceState != null){return;} in your onCreate() in your activity. And instead of replacing a fragment (transaction.replace) use (transaction.add)

Comment: Thanks man, there is no technical issue with getting the fragment displayed on top. That works just fine. My question is only, if this can only work with a `RelativeLayout` as a root element of the activities.

Comment: I see, so it is overlapping fragments that you are using? If so, than no to your question. I have used view on top of views with a number of layouts. My root element has been anything from a frameLayout to a tableLayout, and i can get a view on top of these views.